# Why is there extra space around the text of my button?

Tags: android, button, nine-patch

There seems to be padding around the text inside my button.  It is a custom button uses 9 patches.  **I have not altered the 9 patch files in 2 years**.  I'm not sure why, all the sudden, my buttons are really tall.

Here is a screenshot of what the button looks like in my app:

[image]

When you compare it to the 9 patch files, it doesn't seem like all of that extra space should be there.  Here are my 9 patch files (there are 2 states to the button):

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the flat horizontal and vertical edges can expand, and the text is given the same area to write in.  Only the round corners are off limits.

So why is there are this extra space, particularly above and below the text?

Here is my `Button` declared in the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login2_facebook"
        android:layout_width="140dip"
        android:layout_height="55dip"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login2_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_greenbutton"
        android:shadowColor="@color/dark_green"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the "selector_greenbutton" drawable for the 2 button states:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/greenbutton" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/greenbuttonp" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/greenbutton" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/greenbutton" />
</selector>
```

I'm really not sure what is causing this.

Comment: is the output remain same when you fix  android:layout_height value?

Comment: Does the container layout set some padding (or it could be in the styles)? Because the paddings found in `values-11` and `values-14` could be too much.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have updated the original post to show the container layout.

Comment: @DROIDcoder Setting a fixed layout_height indeed changes the height of the button, but this is not sufficient.  The button should have no problem wrapping around the text anyway.  That seems like more of a band aid than solving the actual problem.

Comment: @DROIDcoder Setting a fixed layout_height indeed changes the height of the button, but this is not sufficient.  The button should have no problem wrapping around the text anyway.  That seems like more of a band aid than solving the actual problem.

Comment: May be a different app theme is applied.

Comment: Is there a way for me to specify a preferred spacing?